# RegExp to find value in the array

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is my JavaScript with a RegExp which does not work, I cannot find the correct syntax:

```
var arr = ['111', '222|12', '333'];
new RegExp('\\b' + value + '\\b').test(arr);
value = '111'; //true
value = '222'; //true
value = '12'; //true
```

I need avoid numbers following a `|`, meaning that a test with number `12` should return false. So values 111, 222 and 333 must yield true only.

I just know that the first `\\b` must be replaced with a syntax to avoid the `|` character.

Comment: The `test` method takes a string, not an array. So it is coerced to *one* string. You need to iterate  `arr`.

Comment: Maybe `arr.map(x => (m = x.match(/^\d+/)) ? m[0] : "")` will do? This will grab the first 1+ digits from every array item, or empty string on no match.

Comment: @trincot Strange! It return true on 111, 222, 13 and 333 - I think that can be used, just found syntax to avoid ```|``` symbol

Comment: It returns true because you don't test that the string contains anything else before or after it. It is not strange at all. Note that it would also find `111,222`. Is that really what you want?

Comment: @trincot You have true, okay.. I thought that working, my bad!

Comment: So why do you have this `|` in some array values? What is the purpose of what comes after it?

Comment: NB/ don't put "[Solved]" in the title. On Stack Overflow there is not such a thing as a solved question. You can however mark an answer as accepted.

Comment: I used ```new RegExp('(?:^|,)' + value.split('|')[0] + '\\b').test(arr)``` as one line solution (ES5), but solution bellow is useful ofc,... value after "|" ? In short, a small local application, values are not particularly handled. First value is ID, second one is optional option. I need to find out if ID exists and remove it. Then is the array used in a cycle and whole value is sent through AJAX (third-party web app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an array to the `test` method, while it expects a string. So the array gets coerced to a comma separated string "111,222|23,333". Obviously that makes your tests succeed, but you would also get a match with "111,222".

Using a regular expression for this seems overkill. You can use `split("|")` to get rid of the part that follows a pipe symbol, and then just do an equality test on each remaining value. Use the `some` method to iterate until you get such a match:

```js
function isMatch(arr, value) {
    return arr.some(s => s.split('|')[0] === value);
}
var arr = ['111', '222|12', '333'];
console.log(isMatch(arr, '111')); //true
console.log(isMatch(arr, '222')); //true
console.log(isMatch(arr, '333')); //true
console.log(isMatch(arr, '12')); //false
```